# Reading database with JDBC

Tags: java, database, jdbc

I created a table using JDBC and SQLite in one of my programs. Now I'm trying to read specific values from the database. I'm trying to get the very last ordernumber, but I get an error. I've put my code below. Not sure what's wrong:

```
try {
    String sql = "SELECT ordernumber FROM orderTable ORDERBY ordernumber LIMIT 1 DESC";
    Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
    Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
    System.out.println(rs.getInt("ordernumber"));
} catch (SQLException e) {
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
}
```

Comment: Neither am I sure, whats wrong. Pls add the error and a call stack of the exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can update the SQL to the correct syntax and then run it.

```
String sql = "SELECT ordernumber FROM orderTable ORDERBY ordernumber LIMIT 1 DESC";
```

(right one):

```
String sql = "SELECT ordernumber FROM orderTable ORDER BY ordernumber DESC LIMIT 1 ";
```

Answer (score 0):

change

```
String sql = "SELECT ordernumber FROM orderTable ORDERBY ordernumber LIMIT 1 DESC";
```

to

```
String sql = "SELECT ordernumber FROM orderTable ORDER BY ordernumber LIMIT 1 DESC";
```